# Framerate drops, tearing appears when making SDL window resizable

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I just moved from SDL 1.2 to SDL 2.0 and I initially enjoyed similar performance (65+ FPS), then added Vsync in the renderer options and enjoyed a smooth 60 FPS with no tearing, then I added the flag SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE and the framerate dropped a lot (40 FPS without Vsync, 30 FPS with) and tearing appeared even with Vsync and side-scrolling became quite jittery. Whether or not I do anything to handle the resize event doesn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using SDL 2.0.3 on VS2010 compiling in 64 bits. Here's the relevant code:

```
// This creates the window and everything associated with it
void graphics_init(srgb_t **sfb)
{
    static int init=1;

    if (init)
    {
        init = 0;
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow ( VERSION,            // window title
                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,    // initial x position
                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,    // initial y position
                    0,              // width, in pixels
                    0,              // height, in pixels
                    SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED);   // flags

    SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &kW, &kH);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, kW, kH);

    *sfb = calloc (kW*kH, sizeof(srgb_t));
}

int main()
{
    graphics_init(&sfb);

    while (exit_flag==0)
    {
        ... // main loop stuff that fills my buffer sfb

        // Blits sfb buffer to screen
        SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, sfb, kW * sizeof(srgb_t));

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, as I can not quite reproduce the phenomenon... Have you tried OR'ing `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED` with `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` in the `SDL_CreateRenderer()` call, to enable hardware acceleration?

Comment: Just tried, I get the same result.

Comment: While it is close to impossible to say without complete picture of what's going on in background, my best guess is that it interferes with your window manager's composition. From your compiler I guess you're running it on windows; can you try changing appearance theme to classic and testing again?

Comment: Windows 7 x64 with Aero on, yes. I changed it to classic and the problem is gone. The problem is also gone when adding SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS. So what can we do about it?

Comment: I don't have much experience with it. But if you have 65 fps in fullscreen, it probably means your performance reserves are close to its limits. Windowed mode with compositing enabled is slower, as expected - to the point it no longer can sustain 60fps; this is when tearing starts. So, best thing you should do is increasing performance of your program to push it beyond 60fps point even in windowed mode. Start with changing your drawing approach - filling buffer and sending it to drawing on each frame isn't GPU-friendly; use SDL textures for more things, not just final draw.

Comment: When I drop the performance (by drawing more things for instance) when things work normally I get either 30 FPS or 20 FPS with no tearing, so there's clearly something going on other than a performance issue that brings tearing back. Why would Aero make things so much worse than classic mode anyway? As for the drawing approach it cannot be changed, one reason among many is that my internal framebuffer is in linear-valued 1.15 fixed point arithmetic format per channel.

Btw I signed up on the libsdl forum days ago and I still cannot post or contact anyone about it, any idea what's up with that?

Comment: It is quite simple with compositing. Aero uses GPU for its effects, your drawing is done to its internal buffer (i.e. render to texture) and only then pushed to screen by window manager. This approach essentially kills vsync in your application - since you no longer controls display, you have no saying in when your image will be displayed. How vsync works in that situation is completely up to driver and WM - e.g. I always have tearing on nvidia GPU in windowed mode, but not in fullscreen. Fullscreen disables compositing for performance gains, so you getting different results here.

Comment: Okay, but it still seems weird that I get vsync and great performance in a small window, or even in a resizable window without Aero on, but not if that window is resizable only when Aero is on. Seems like there must be something in the my code-SDL-the driver-Aero chain that's not acting right.